# functional javascript - how could I generalize this code that correlates parallel async requests with their results?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, asynchronous, underscore.js, monads

```
/**
 * takes a list of componentIDs to load, relative to componentRoot
 * returns a promise to the map of (ComponentID -> componentCfg)
 */
function asyncLoadComponents (componentRoot, components) {

    var componentCfgs = {};

    function asyncLoadComponentCfg(component) {
        var url = _.sprintf("%s/%s", componentRoot, component);
        var promise = util.getJSON(url);
        promise.done(function(data) {
            componentCfgs[component] = data;
        });
        return promise;
    }

    var promises = _.map(components, asyncLoadComponentCfg);
    var flattenedPromise = $.when.apply(null, promises);
    var componentCfgPromise = flattenedPromise.pipe(function() {
        // componentCfgs is loaded now
        return $.Deferred().resolve(componentCfgs).promise();
    });

    return componentCfgPromise;
}


var locale = 'en-US';
var componentRoot = '/api/components';
var components = ['facets', 'header', 'DocumentList'];
function buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs) { /* code goes here */ }

$.when(asyncLoadComponents(componentRoot, components)).done(function(componentCfgs) {
    buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a sample in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgdNA/1/), with some values and functions mocked-up to use jsFiddle API.

Here's the actual code, with notes in the comments:

```
//personally, I like comma separated variables preferrably the 
//"comma-before style". But it's personal preference.

//JS "hoists" up variable and function declarations higher in the scope.
//To avoid unexpected behaviour, and so that they are easier to find,
//we move them to the top of their scopes
var locale = 'en-US'
  , componentRoot = '/api/components'
  , components = ['facets', 'header', 'DocumentList']
  ;

function buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs) {}

//load our components
function asyncLoadComponents(componentRoot, components) {

      //our configuration collector
  var componentCfgs = {}

      //we create a promises array by mapping each value to a function
    , promises = _.map(components, function (component) {

        //we use the promise of a getJSON request (Assuming this is jQuery).
        //since you just concatenated the url values, we can just concatenate with +
        return util.getJSON(componentRoot+'/'+component).done(function (data) {

          //when getJSON resolves, we put the data in the collector
          componentCfgs[component] = data
        });
      });

  //as of jQuery 1.8, pipe is deprecated in favor of then. However, then
  //is designed to act like pipe, and instead of resolving with the value
  //we return the value instead
  return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function () {
    return componentCfgs;
  })
}

//we model the function to return a promise that we'll listen to instead
//of having a $.when here. That way, we'll deal with less code and promises
asyncLoadComponents(componentRoot,components).done(function(componentCfgs) {

  //here, all configs have loaded and stored to componentCfgs
  buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs);
});
```

Packed code looks like this, tons shorter:

```
var locale = 'en-US',
  componentRoot = '/api/components',
  components = ['facets', 'header', 'DocumentList'];

function buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs) {}

function asyncLoadComponents(componentRoot, components) {
  var componentCfgs = {}, promises = _.map(components, function (component) {
      return util.getJSON(componentRoot + '/' + component).done(function (data) {
        componentCfgs[component] = data
      })
    });
  return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function () {
    return componentCfgs
  })
}

asyncLoadComponents(componentRoot, components).done(function (componentCfgs) {
  buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have fully generalized thanks to Joseph's help. So this could parallelize and sequence by key arbitrary async things, like say a database query to load objects by ID.

library code:

```
/**
 * perform multiple requests in parallel, returning a Promise[Map[Key, Response]]
 * @fBuildUrl function that can build a URL from a key
 * @fAsyncRequest function of one argument that returns a promise
 * @keys the things to load, that fBuildUrl can build a URL from
 *
 * use case: takes a list of componentIDs to load, relative to componentRoot
 * returns a promise to the map of (ComponentID -> componentCfg)
 */
exports.asyncParallel = function (fBuildUrl, fAsyncRequest, keys) {

    var responses = {};
    var asyncLoadOne = function (key) {
        var url = fBuildUrl(key);
        return fAsyncRequest(url).done(function(data) {
            responses[key] = data;
        });
    };

    var promises = _.map(keys, asyncLoadOne);
    return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        return responses;
    });
};
```

application code:

```
var components = ['tmfFacets', 'tmfHeader', 'tmfDocumentList'];

function buildUrl (key) {
    return componentRoot + "/" + key;
}

util.asyncParallel(buildUrl, util.getJSON, components).done(function(componentConfigs) {
    window.page = new DocListPage(locale, componentConfigs, DocListPageRouter);
});
```

can we do even better, or is this it?

Comment: `util.asyncParallel` already returns a promise, you can chain `done` directly. Using `$.when` to judge it's return is redundant.